# import CF status to local environment with CDK

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

I'm using the AWS CDK v2 to deploy my changes to the project.

Thing is that I am running `cdk diff` locally and then getting output of ALL nested stacks, so mostly the changed (times amount of nested stacks)

```bash
[~] AWS::CloudFormation::Stack Name
 ├─ [~] NestedTemplate
 │   └─ [~] .Resources:
 │       ├─ [~] .CDKMetadata:
 │       │   └─ [~] .Properties:
 │       │       └─ [~] .Analytics:
 │       │           ├─ [-] v2:deflate64:H4sIAAAAAAAA/xxxAAAA=
 │       │           └─ [+] v2:deflate64:H4sIAAAAAAAA/xxxAAAA
```

hashes and the actual diff somehow squashed inside, which is really readable...

However, I am not getting this when deploying through the gitlab worker (so the host which is actually deploying changes)...

**Question:**

Is there a way (instead resyncing cdk.out folder from worker host) to pull the state directly from the AWS project CloudFormation to my local host ? Or is there already some feature request like that, which I have not seen ?

Comment: Does the gitlab worker also run `cdk diff`? How exactly does the output differ?

Comment: @gshpychka the difference is that I am getting diff from all 16 Nested stacks which are not changing (mostly the .Analytics hash) vs i should get only diff for the one only i did changed

Comment: Can you provide the actual exact output? You say "mostly" - what else differs?

Comment: I cant give you an output here, unfortunately. But if you are working with Nested stacks you should get the idea. if this cant be solved here i will create ticket to support or to github

Comment: Unfortunately the information provided isn't enough to diagnose the issue.